# Style window not appearing in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

In Word 2007, when I click the expand button on the Styles area of the ribbon, nothing happens. I have tried reinstalling Word but am still having this issue.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Still having this issue anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the menu to come back by deleting the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/12.0/Word/Data/Toolbars
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see for "nothing to happen" is that you opened it, and it is now off-screen. Since it memorizes its position, it will open it back to the last place where you put it.

Did you use it in a multi-screen situation recently?

I can't find, unfortunately, an option to reset the position of these windows, for now.

Comment: Thanks for the message. I am actually RDC'ing into a box that has no monitor. I will try and get on the actual PC to see if that helps.

Comment: Let me know if you find out any information on how to reposition the windows.

Comment: I already cleared my Office/common registry and this did not help.

Comment: @joe - unfortunately I can't find anything besides resetting the registry keys.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried reinstalling word and still experiencing the problem.